# error: can't allocate region Swift Xcode 9.2 iPhone X

Tags: swift, xcode, maps, malloc, iphone-x

I'm figuring out a really strange problem. My app is crashing just on iPhone X and just on the device, not on the simulator. Keeping a look to the debug instrument it seems that the RAM is reaching it's maximum and it's crashing.

On the debug area it's appearing:

```
    ZTL City(6387,0x16c707000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=9437184) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ZTL City(6387,0x16c81f000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=9437184) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ZTL City(6387,0x16c2eb000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=9437184) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ZTL City(6387,0x16c707000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=9437184) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ZTL City(6387,0x16c377000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=9437184) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ZTL City(6387,0x16c793000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=9437184) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ZTL City(6387,0x16c81f000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=9437184) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Someone knows why? It's happening only on iPhone X and straight on the device when FlyOver is enabled from the Map tab.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Pietro Messineo , did you find any workaround  for above issue , since last couple of days i am also facing same issue .

Comment: Hi @ZarnaParikh no idea... It was an issue related to the memory management only with new iPhone models. Then Apple released an update for Xcode and the issue has been solved automagically.